# Tem como fazer uma simulação 3D no ROS usando rviz no contexto de swarm inteligent?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tem como fazer uma simulação 3D no ROS usando rviz no contexto de swarm inteligent?

Preciso que na simulacao eu demonstre as propriedades do Swmar...

Alguém pode me ajudar?

alex.procopio@hotmail.com

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72913/tem-como-fazer-uma-simula%C3%A7%C3%A3o-3d-no-ros-usando-rviz-no-contexto-de-swarm-inteligent?/) by [alexprocopio](https://answers.ros.org/users/5944/alexprocopio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usando um simulador como [Stage](http://ros.org/wiki/stage), você pode gerar um grande número de robôs. Estes robôs podem ser controlados através de ROS. Supondo que você tenha o código que você gostaria que cada robô executar, então esta é uma maneira que você pode demonstrar robótica de enxame.

Translation:
Using a simulator like [Stage](http://ros.org/wiki/stage), you can generate large numbers of robots. These robots can be controlled through ROS. Assuming that you have the code that you would like each robot to run, then this is one way that you can demonstrate swarm robotics.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3